# Check box in django redux form. I am using django-redux

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I have added two check box in django redux registration form. Now, I can check both the option, But I want user to select any one at a time. How to achieve that?
Below is my code

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class UserSelection(models.Model):
    employer = models.BooleanField()
    candidate = models.BooleanField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

class MyRegForm(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
    employer = forms.BooleanField()
    candidate = forms.BooleanField()
```

regbackend.py

```
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView
from .forms import MyRegForm
from .models import UserSelection

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    form_class = MyRegForm

    def register(self, form_class):
        new_user = super(MyRegistrationView, self).register(form_class)
        p = form_class.cleaned_data['employer']
        q = form_class.cleaned_data['candidate']
        new_profile = UserSelection.objects.create(user=new_user, employer=p, candidate=q)
        new_profile.save()
        return new_user
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want two boolean fields? If you had a char field with choices, the form will only allow you to select one choice.

```
USER_TYPE_CHOICES = [
    ('employer', 'Employer'),
    ('candidate', 'Candidate'),
]

class UserSelection(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

If you really want two boolean fields, you can write a clean method for your model.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class UserSelection(models.Model):
    employer = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    candidate = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def clean(self):
        if self.employer and self.candidate:
            raise ValidationError("You cannot select employer and candidate")
        if not (self.employer or self.candidate):
            raise ValidationError("You must select employer or candidate")
```

Note that you need `blank=True` on your boolean fields to allow the user to leave them unticked.

Comment: if we select one option only, then it is asking to click other option also. How to deactivate that?

Comment: You need to set `blank=True` on the boolean fields to make them optional.